# React Native Navigation library showModal, push, pop relating to the React Native lifecycle

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

Using the 'react native navigation' library

Short:
How does the react native navigator library relate to the react native life cycle. I know it's built on top of native code. It seems you could call showModal, push, pop from several lifecycle steps (componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, ...). Is there a best practice and what are the reasonings.

Details:
I'm currently using react native navigation to build on onboarding flow. During my onboarding flow (midway) there is a trigger for a secondary flow to launch. At this point I open a new modal and push a screen (screenB) into modal #2. I'm running into the issue where screenB will not render unless I enabled JS debug and set a break point within screenB . The break point can be anywhere in that file so long as it gets hit. I have retested this many times and can only get screenB to render if a break point is set.